# How add a paragraph field to a form programmatically?

Tags: forms, blocks, paragraphs

I'm on Drupal 9. I am creating a custom block programmatically with some fields in the configuration form.

However, I need to add a paragraph field and I've found no documentation\working way to do so.

Anyone knows how to do that?  I'd also need to limit the types of entity referenced: e.g. content type "node", bundles "author" and "article".

```
      public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $form['foo'] = [
          '#type' => 'textarea',
          '#title' => $this->t('Foo'),
          '#default_value' => $this->configuration['foo'],
        ];
        
        // how add a paragraph field?

        return $form;
      }
```

Comment: Field widgets are for entity forms - it sounds like you need to add a custom block type and attach the field to that

Comment: @Clive I don't get your suggestion. Could you elaborate more? Thanks.
I'm following [this guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-blocks/create-a-custom-block) to create the custom block and relative form fields.

Comment: What you are trying to add to the form is a field widget. Field widgets are for forms used to create or edit an entity.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thank you, now I understand. So as pointed out by Clive one way I can solve this is to create a custom block via the UI - with the necessary paragrah field(s) - and then add the custom logic necessary via a preprocess function.
 
I can't think to another better way, or is there?

Comment: A custom block type is an entity. You can add any entity field to it, which would use its own widget, for entering its value. I don't think you can find a better way.

Comment: @Giuseppe Create a custom block type in UI, add fields you want to have, export config to files and use hook_form_alter or hook_form_FORM_ID_alter to provide adjustments. If you want to impact the behavoiur of specific paragraph fields then you should use different hooks specifc for altering paragraphs.